# Overkill battery charging circuit?

Tags: pcb-design, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I want some experience in designing electronic circuits, and have chosen to build a battery charging circuit for a possible future PCB. I've tried to follow all the advice I can find online about designing such circuits, and would like to know if there's anything I'm missing or misunderstanding in my final design:

The high-level decisions are as follows:

- The battery is a single cell, lithium-ion battery with a cutoff voltage of `4.2V`
- The battery capacity is `2500mAH`, and should charge at around `0.2C` or `500mA`, and discharge at `0.5C` or `1250mA` maximally.
- The load will draw around `~300mAH` max.
- The voltage provided to power the load should be exactly `3.6V`

I will need to choose the following devices carefully:

- An appropriate battery management IC
- A low dropout voltage regulator

---

#### Result

[image]

#### Commentary

1. **MAX1811**: I chose the MAX1811 as my battery management IC. It allows up to `500mA` of current, which should be enough to (1) charge the battery at the recommended current level (assuming no load) (2) charge even when the load is drawing current (albeit slower). I've connected it to a USB port for power, which should provide `5V` and `500mA` maximally per the USB2.0 spec. This is within the maximum ratings for the IC. I used the recommended capacitor size on the IN pin, and a larger one for the BATT pin (as there are also other devices connected that I accounted for later)
2. **LTC3025**: as my low-dropout voltage regulator. This IC can lower the voltage it outputs. I used the formula provided [in the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3025fd.pdf) which is `v_out = 0.4 (1 + R2/R1)` with `R1=24K` and `R2=3K` to get: `0.4 (1 + 24/3) = 3.6V`. Of course, this assumes I am getting `4.0V` in.
3. **ADP2503**: When looking at the application example for the LTC3025, I saw they used this IC with it in order to eliminate unwanted noise coming from the battery. Therefore, I decided to also include this buck/boost IC and configured it to buck mode. The voltage in is expected to be 4.2, and I set it to output 4.0 in accordance with what I expected as input to the LTC3025. Per the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP2503_2504.pdf) I used the build in (just a voltage divider) formula (`V_out = (R1 + R2) / R2 * V_ref`) where `V_ref` is typically `500mV` and chose `R1=330K` and `R2=47k` because the datasheet asked the total resistance of the divider be around `400K`. This gives me just about `4V` out.

#### Criticisms

The only comments I have had so far (in person by a passing friend) is that my design is too complicated and that the ADP2504 is unnecessary. However, I would like to see if I can get some good advice on what I could improve on here from a variety of other perspectives!

I also was unsure as to how to choose the capacitor size to sit on the net between the MAX1811 and the LTC3025 and ADP2503. All of them recommend capacitors be placed on their inputs/outputs. But they all share a common net! I just chose a larger capacitor size of 20uF, and then split it into two 10uF capacitors on a friends direction (faster discharge). This is larger (in total) than all the recommended output capacitor sizes combined for that net, so I thought it would work. But I don't have a proper logical approach for this step.

Comment: Have you looked at the discharge curve for a typical Li-Ion cell? It doesn't stay up at 4.2V for very long and spends much of its life at around the 3.7V range. Your ADP2503 in buck mode set to 4V isn't going to work very well.

Comment: @brhans Ah yeah, I didn't realize. The buck/boost will quickly no longer be "bucking" when the voltage drops. Hmm. What do you propose I do? Should I adjust the resistors expecting something like 3.8-4.0V in, or use another type of IC?

Comment: Actually - now that I've skimmed the datasheet - I see that the ADP2503 automatically switches mode between buck/buck-boost/boost - in which case it's not a problem that you've set its output for 4V. It'll switch modes appropriately as the cell voltage drops.

Comment: @brhans Yeah, I also setup a SPICE simulation to see how the ADP2503 responds with my reference configuration in response to V_in being swept from 3.6 to 4.2. It seems to work as expected so I assume it practice it will be okay!